# Хоткей "выделить слово", где стоит курсор, Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, hotkeys

Перебираюсь на Visual Studio по-немногу и некоторые удобства, которые доступны в VSCode, пытаюсь найти.

Как выделить одно слово, в котором находится курсор?

В VSCode это - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

В Visual Studio чего только не нашел и справа и слева от курсора, но не целое слово, когда курсор находится на середине данного слова

Вот это сочетание <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> / <kbd>←</kbd>, но это не то, что я ищу

Comment: `Ctrl+W`. Ой, спасибо, мил человек! Теперь сам буду пользоваться хоткеем. ЗЫ: нагуглил только что

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, как так то... я пролез всю доку вот эту https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022. Как только не искал, сегодня не мой день))) Ответите?

Comment: ассоциация https://stackoverflow.com/q/3433730/10562663

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

Я загуглил "visual studio select word" и ответ нашёлся на одном очень полезном [сайте](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3433730/5045688). :)

Можно задать свою комбинацию в настройках: Options > Environment > Keyboard > Edit.SelectCurrentWord.

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю описание, как найти, если настройка отличается от указанной в ответе

1. Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard
2. Ввести значение `edit.SelectCurrentWord`
3. В окошке `Shortcuts for selected command` будет указано сочетание клавиш

В виде гифки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]